# Calling Angular 6 Component method from Java script file

Tags: javascript, angular6

I am trying to call a method in my Angular 6 component from the Javascript and i am not sure how to

New.js file has the below code.

function testJScall() {
  alert('Welcome to custom js');

}

I am able to successfully call this Javascript function from my component by referring it in the Index.html (and doing the related changes in components.ts). After alert i would like the javascript to call a method back in the same component.ts. Can some one help me with the call back to the component.

Comment: Why is (was) this tagged with C#?

Comment: I have removed it , any thoughts on it?